# Crossings in an Eulerian Trail

Tags: graph-theory

Exercise 11.2 in [Graph Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201410338) by Harary says

> Every plane eulerian graph contains an eulerian trial that never crosses itself.

What does it mean for a trail to not cross itself?  The book does not give a formal definition of this notion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the "formal" definition, but informally it means just what you would think. If you regard the Eulerian trail as a curve in the plane, the curve does not cross itself, in the sense that the graphs of $y=0$ and $y=x$ cross at the origin, but the graphs of $y=0$ and $y=x^2$ touch without crossing.

For instance, consider the plane Eulerian graph with vertices $v=(0,0)$, $w=(1,0)$, $x=(1,1)$, $y=(-1,-1)$, $z=(-1,0)$, and straight-line edges $vw,wx,xv,vy,yz,zv$. The Eulerian trail $z,v,w,x,v,y,z$ crosses itself at $v$, but the Eulerian trail $z,v,x,w,v,y,z$ does not cross itself.

**P.S.** Following a suggestion by the OP, here's an attempt at defining a self-crossing for an Eulerian trail in a plane graph $G$. The trail crosses itself at a vertex $v$ if, among the edges of $G$ that are incident with $v$, there are four distinct edges $a,b,c,d$ which occur in the cyclic order $(a,b,c,d)$ in the clockwise ordering of the edges incident with $v$, and such that the edges $a$ and $c$ are traversed consecutively (though not necessarily in that order) in the trail, and the same goes for the edges $b$ and $d$.

Comment: Your graph is neither Eulerian nor plane. I think you mean for your last edge $zw$ to be $zv$.

Comment: With the above change to your graph, I agree with your example, but you need to define this formally. Let me help. At each vertex $v$ of a plane graph, there is a (say clockwise) cyclic ordering on $N(v)$, the neighbors of $v$. Can you come up with a formal definition using these cyclic orderings?

Comment: Re: P.S. Yes, this is also what I think Harary meant.

Answer (score 0):

A planar trail "crosses itself" if you cannot draw it without edges crossing.  Connecting at a vertex does not count as crossing.

Comment: That definition doesn't make sense. Then every Eulerian trail in every plane graph does not cross itself.